# How to loop my definition? ~sum values untill limit is reached and loop again for the rest

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

I'm struggling with while looping.
I have a list with Widths (double or integer, doesn't matter - don't need precision). 
Basically I need number of items that sum is lower than limit. 
Now it finds only the first number. 
I'm not able to adapt while loop, so it would start calculation over again with the rest of items. 
This code give 6 as output, cause sum(100,300,30,100,50,80) < limit = 850.
The desired loop would do this:

1st iteration: start from 0 until sum meet limit: [100,300,30,100,50,80,400,120,500,75,180] -> give 6

2nd iteration: start from the next(last index from 1st run +1) item and iterate over the rest: 400,120,500,75,180 -> give 2

3rd: iterate over 500,75,180 -> give 3

Number of widths = unknown

if width > limit -> break the code

```
Widths = [100,300,30,100,50,80,400,120,500,75,180]

def items(nums,limit):  
    sum=0   
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):  
        sum += nums[i]
        if sum>limit-1:  
          return i

print (items(Widths,850))
```

I'd like to have output like this:
[6,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a return immediately exits out of the function. You need to store instead of returning, and go from there.
I have also pointed out some comments in code as well that should help.

```
Widths = [100,300,30,100,50,80,400,120,500,75,180]

def items(nums,limit):  
    acc = 0  #do not use sum as a variable name. it "shadows" or hides the builtin function with same name
    length = 0
    result = []
    for num in nums:  #You do not really need indexes here, so you can directly iterate on items in nums list. 
        acc += num 
        if acc >= limit: #greater than or equal to. 
            result.append(length)
            acc = num
            length = 1
        else:
            length += 1
    result.append(length) #if you need the last length even if it does not add up.
    return result


print (items(Widths,850))
#Output:
[6, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. I was pretty close with my code (a lil bit different than I posted). The only flaw is when value exceeds a limit it gives 1 instead of breaking code, but it's easy.
Previously I tried to get all values with range function. So basically when limit was reached it would loop again from a certain start.